# Spring Boot: How to Disable JNDI lookup and use spring.datasource instead for Testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I would like my main Spring Boot application to configure my datasource using `JNDI` via

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/MyAppDS
```

in my `application.properties` file.

At time, I'd like to use a different datasource settings to be able to run my test cases using the in-memory datasource (i.e. `H2`). 
I've created a separate `application.properties` file under `src/test/resources` and have the following in it:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

However, the test files don't seem to like this and I get the following error:

```
[main] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jboss/datasources/MyAppDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

causing my tests to fail.

**Things I've done:**

Renamed my properties file to `testapplication.properties` in `src/test/resources` and updating the content with

```
spring.mydatasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.mydatasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.mydatasource.username=sa
spring.mydatasource.password=sa
```

and the adding the following annotations to my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/web-resources")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:testapplication.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mydatasource")
public class BrandsSvcTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;  

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
         this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

      // ... my test cases
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Drop the ConfigurationProperties annotation, and use the standard properties names in your testapplication.properties file.

Comment: It doesn't work. That's why i tried adding the Config annotation.

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: Let me strip down my project to a minimum viable implementation and try your suggestion.

Comment: You might also have to use the AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation

Comment: @JBNizet the `AutoConfigureTestDatabase` annotation did the trick. Please put your answer in the solution area so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Feel free to provide a cmplete answer by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same situation as the question asked and the same error. This worked for me.

You can add the following to your src/test/resources/application.properties so that jndi lookup doesn't happen during tests -

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration
```